# F# : How to execute multiple statements in a loop

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am new to functional programming and I have been trying to execute these statements in the loop but it gives me an error saying tabs are not allowed in f#. please help. This might contain more errors please correct me if I am wrong.

```
open System
let sum:int32=0,sum2:int32=0,sum3:int32=0;
let function1(num:int32) =
for i = 1 to num do
  sum = sum + i
  sum2 = sum2 + (i+1)
  sum3 = sum3 + (i+2)
printfn "%i %i %i" sum sum2 sum3

function(11)
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody linked [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabsSpacesBoth). I also added a version with higher order functions, etc. that retuns a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should read some introduction to basic [F# syntax](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-in-60-seconds/). This below is not very idiomatic F#, one objective of functional programming is to avoid mutable variables.

```
open System
let mutable sum = 0
let mutable sum2 = 0
let mutable sum3 = 0
let function1 num =
    for i = 1 to num do
    sum <- sum + i
    sum2 <- sum2 + (i+1)
    sum3 <- sum3 + (i+2)
    printfn "%i %i %i" sum sum2 sum3

function1 11
```

You should run this function a couple of times and see why this is not a good idea. Hint, you should at least define the mutable variables inside the function scope.

**Edit**
And here's a version with a variety of list manipulation functions:

```
let sumFunc2 num =
    [for i in 1..num -> 
     List.init i (fun x -> x+1)] 
    |> List.map List.sum
    |> List.mapi (fun i x -> [x;x+i+1;x+2+2*i])

sumFunc2 4
```

Comment: shouldn't you have a "|> List.last" at the end in sumFunc2?

Comment: @HenrikHansen That's a good question and really depends on the OP's intent. In his Q the printfn is outside the for loop, but it won't work that way. The reason is that the OP defines the sum variables, then defines a function, then runs the function. In fact that way it won't print anything (well 0,0,0 for the first time). That's why I pulled the printfn inside the for loop. Now it's possible that the printfn is still inside the function but outside the for loop. Then you can certainly tag on a List.last, but the advantage is that you can if you want but you don't need to do that.

Comment: @HenrikHansen or rather bad indentation... Anyway, one can swap the fold to scan in your function as well. So it's not such a big deal. I like the fold/scan solution. Hopefull someone will post a recursive one and we're done. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the error message speaks for itself: Don't use tabs, use spaces.

Other than that (and the fact that you can't use commas to separate bindings with let like you did), your code looks syntactically valid, that is to do multiple things in a loop, you indent them at the same level, as you did.

Semantically it won't do what you want though. = is the equality operator in F#, not assignment. Plus variables are immutable by default. To do what you want, you'll need to declare the variables as mutable and use the assignment operator `<-`.

That said though, the result of this won't be functional programming, just imperative programming done in F#. The functional way would be to use higher order functions and/or recursion and no mutable variables at all.

Comment: this for example is I'm sure not syntactically valid: `let sum:int32=0,sum2:int32=0,sum3:int32=0;
`

Comment: @s952163 You're right, I missed that. I was only looking at the loop. That seems to be the only thing though.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, mutable variables are (nearly) almost bad in functional programming/F#. Instead it's all about processing sequences of data.

I often find `List.fold` very useful in places where I would have used an iteration in other languages like C++ or C#.

A simple solution with List.fold for your question could be:

```
open System

let tripleSum n = 
  [1..n] |> List.fold (fun (s1, s2, s3) x -> (s1 + x, s2 + 1 + x, s3 + 2 + x)) (0, 0, 0)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let sum1, sum2, sum3 = tripleSum 3
  printfn "%d, %d, %d" sum1 sum2 sum3 

  Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

In tripleSum above the last `(0, 0, 0)` is the initial seed values for the three sums, and they sums up by the fold function `(fun (s1, s2, s3) ->...` called for each element in the list `[1..n]`